# Why does Microsoft Photos convert images to greyscale more efficiently than OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, photo

I have a folder full of jpg images which I would like to reduce in size. It are colour photos of black and white sketches, so the first thing I try is to convert them to greyscale. I experimented a bit and tried two things which should give the same result:

1. use Microsoft Photos to convert an image to greyscale by putting the colour slider to -100
2. use OpenCV to convert the images to greyscale with the command `cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)`.

To my surprise the first method reduced the size of the image significantly more than the second method. Why is this? Also, can this better method be somehow easily implemented in Python? I would like to automate the process, and in Microsoft Photos I can't do this. Is there perhaps an even more efficient method?

PS: If you have other ideas on how I can compress the images, I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: For JPG, the quality parameter has a large effect on file size and compression artifacts. High quality (100) will have larger file and fewer artifacts. Low quality (<50) will have smaller file and more artifacts.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you provided your input image and the Microsoft and OpenCV output images along with your code.

Comment: how do you save the image?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the fault of OpenCV.

You have two operations here.

0. loading a compressed image file into bitmap data in RAM
1. color space conversion, color to gray
2. saving bitmap data into a compressed image file

And #2 is the issue here. When you say "efficiently", you mean disk space.

It seems that OpenCV and MS Photos have different defaults for the compression ratio. OpenCV's `imwrite` does take a `params` argument in which you can determine the JPEG compression quality.

If you need to batch-convert photos, look at [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php).